# Coded UI Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I'm working with Coded UI on Windows 10 Mobile and would like to be able to send keypress events (e.g. Letters or Numbers) to various XAML controls during execution of the tests. I'm wondering if this is possible? Or is coming in a future update to Coded UI?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not currently supported in Coded UI.

I have raised a feature request to the Visual Studio Development Team: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/13731465-vs2015-to-allow-windows-phone-coded-ui-tests-to-ge

If you need this feature, please vote for it.